# Cut strings separated by comma in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I want to read my sql database values and assign them in to variables which I will be using for further processing.

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host='x.x.x.x',
  user="admin",
  password="secret",
  database="dbname"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM dbname.bb_users")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

The following values are returned from my DB:

```
(78, 0, 2, b'', 0, '63.15.172.56', 1646404832, 'mozz@abc.com', Itally, 1646404832, 1646404873, 1646404832, 0, 'viewmc.php')
(79, 0, 2, b'', 0, '10.76.234.152', 1646988672, 'fenster@yahoo.com', India, 1646988672, 1646989676, 1646988672, 1646988813, 'viewtp.php')
(80, 0, 2, b'', 0, '63.14.61.115', 1648820721, 'frans@hotmail.com', France, 1648820721, 1648820721, 1648820721, 0, 'viewrc.php')
(81, 0, 2, b'', 0, '63.15.190.171', 1648820770, 'mozzillo@gmail.com', London, 1648820770, 1648821169, 1648820770, 0, 'view.php')
(82, 0, 2, b'', 0, '63.15.189.113', 1648821062, 'fiewood@yahoo.com', America, 1648821062, 1648821598, 1648821062, 1648821181, 'purge.php')
(83, 0, 2, b'', 0, '63.13.134.216', 1649430673, 'joseph@outlook.com', China, 1649430673, 1649701711, 1649430673, 1649701685, 'view.php')
```

I would want to read every 6th (IP Address), 8th (email), and 9th (country) values separated by comma and assign to the below variables

IP Address = 6th value, Email = 8th value, Location = 9th value

Comment: So `email = x[7]` etc... ?

Comment: It looks like `x` is a tuple and not a string, so as the comment above states, you can just access the element you want with it's index in the tuple, e.g,: `ipaddress = x[5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `myresult` contains a list of tuples. You can access multidimensional arrays like this: (one example)

first specify the tuple you want to access:

```
tuple_of_interest = myresult[n]    #n is the indexnumber of the element
```

then you want access the elements in the tuple:

```
ip = tuple_of_interest[5]
e_mail = tuple_of_interest[7]
country = tuple_of_interest[8]
```

keep in mind indexing starts at 0...

Answer (score 1):

```
(78, 0, 2, b'', 0, '63.15.172.56', 1646404832, 'mozz@abc.com', Itally, 1646404832, 1646404873, 1646404832, 0, 'viewmc.php')
```

Are you sure your database gave you `Itally` with a typo and not between `''`?

---

You can access your `tuple`s this way:

```
for my_tuple in myresult:
   ip = my_tuple[7]
   email = my_tuple[9]
   location = my_tuple[10]
```

And maybe save the data into a `list` of `dict`ionaries?

```
res: list[dict[str, int | str]] = []
for my_tuple in myresult:
    res.append({
        'ip' = my_tuple[7],
        'email' = my_tuple[9],
        'location' = my_tuple[10]
    })
```

Then you will be able to access `res` like this:

```
>>> # Lets say you want the ip of the 4th user...
>>> res[3]['ip']
1648820770
```